# How do I make my website available in Google Apps Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have developed a management tool web site using ASP .NET.

Currently users register in the site to use the service. I would like to move it to Google Apps Marketplace.  So that it would be available to google users.

I am quite confused what i should be doing to achieve this. Can anyone provide some useful links explaining how to do it.

Comment: Websites are not linked in the Google Apps Marketplace. Only apps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way for google users to login in your app by their google usernames, use the google oauth api 
and here's the link to become a vendor on the google apps [marketplace](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/createVendorProfile):

Comment: I have 2 requirements 
(1.) I want to list this website in google market place

(2.) Google users should be able to login to the site using their gmail account

How do I do this?